# How to group employees by their firms in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables: `Firms and Employees`

I need a query so that all the Firm records are pulled, and within that query, pull the Employees for each firm.

For example:

```
ABC Company
Smith, John
Johnson, Tim

DEF Inc.
Jones, Mack
Frank, Tom
```

I have tried variations of JOIN, UNION, etc. with no luck....

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT f.FirmName, GROUP_CONCAT(e.EmpName) AS Employees 
FROM Firm f LEFT JOIN Employee e on f.FirmID = e.FirmID
GROUP BY f.FirmID
```

Answer (score 0):

A query like the below will give you a listing of all firms, and the LEFT JOIN includes companies even if it does not have any employees.

```
select f.name firmname, e.name
from firms f
left join employees e on e.firm_id = f.firm_id
order by firmname, e.name
```

From your front end display code, step through the records and whenever the firm name changes, start a new firm section.